# What algorithm does MongoDB use for its pseudo-random cursor?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to extract random documents from my MongoDB database using `$sample` as described [in documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/).

The documentation states:

> $sample uses a pseudo-random cursor to select documents:

However, it does not mention any specific algorithm. Is there any way to validate which algorithm is it?